# is it possible to use electroshock to temporary stop gross motor functions directly on the neural pathway?

Tags: neuroscience, neurology

Is it possible to modify that procedure and use it to send a small electroshock on the specific neural pathway and temporarily stop that gross motor function?

> When the microphone detects unwanted noise—such as a humming airplane engine—it sends a sound wave into the headphone speakers that is 180 degrees out of phase with the bothersome sound. Consequently, the two waves cancel each other out, resulting in silence._

i would like to know if that procedure can be modified with electric currents in the human nervous system, so body movement is stopped, without stopping organs and damaging the body by sending the current directly in the nerve, canceling out the signal.

Comment: You can usually just say "cease all motor functions"

Comment: But seriously, this is an interesting question I may answer in detail later. A major challenge would be distinguishing between motor outflow to the diaphragm and to other skeletal muscle. Paralytic drugs require manual or mechanical ventilation. Paralytic electromagnetic stimulation would have the same challenge. That's if you could isolate motor outflow to skeletal muscle in the first place